# How to remove unnecessary blank line on code formatting in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to remove unnecessary blank line on code formatting in Android Studio?

Comment: Use `Code` > `Reformat Code`

Comment: Hope the following answer works for you

Comment: thanks both answer are good.  upvoted Harshal's but not showing

Comment: Feel free to mark it as accepted.Upvote Works when u have more than 15 reputation point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to configure the number of blank lines in the settings menu : `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings... -> Code Style -> Java(or whatever your language is) -> Blank Lines`
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2023:
I wanted to delete unnecesary lines in XML files, but you can do the same in kotlin files. I'm using Android Studio hedgehog in Windows 10:

Go to `File -> Settings`

[image]

Search typing `style`, select `XML`, in "Keep blank lines" I changed 2 to 1.

[image]

Apply changes, press `Ctrl + A` to select all the code, press `Ctrl + Alt + L` to reformat the code. Multiple blank lines should be reduced to 1 now.