# How to remove unnecessary blank line on code formatting in Android Studio in Import groups

Tags: java, android-studio

How can I get rid of empty lines between imports of different 'Import-groups' with code formatting in Android-Studio? (want delete line 9 and 12)

[image]

With File ->Settings -> Default Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java: set Blank Lines to 0 it doesn't work.

Both not work:
[How to remove unnecessary blank line on code formatting in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020651/how-to-remove-unnecessary-blank-line-on-code-formatting-in-android-studio)
[How to remove unnecessary blank line on code formatting in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118204/how-to-remove-unnecessary-blank-line-on-code-formatting-in-intellij)

Using Android Studio 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Blank" lines section is for spaces in the code file, **but** the Imports section has a *dedicated* tab in Android studio.

Have you played around with these? Does it do what you need?

[image: Import Screen]

It's worth noting that the "default convention" consists of separating packages like so, so unless you have a very valid reason (spacing is not a good one, because you can collapse them by default), I wouldn't bother with that.

Comment: Thx @Martin! That was exactly what I want achieve.